# Populate Exchange Global Address List on iOS

Tags: ios, office-365

Is there a way to populate the Exchange Global Address List of contacts under iOS?

Contacts > Groups > Exchange Global Address List

Currently the list is empty - I can only search for contacts.

iPhone running iOS 8.3.